# What is the difference between 痛み and 疼き?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between 痛み and 疼き?
Both words mean 'pain', 'ache'. Is there any difference in usage of these words except of frequency?
Feel free to provide examples.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

痛み is the general term to describe pain or hurting, whereas 疼き describes a more specific *throbbing* or *pounding* type of pain. Examples given by [Weblio (Japanese)](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%81%9A%E3%81%8F) are a pounding tooth ache (or bad tooth) or scar tissue pain.